# Rmi getDate() Program gives error at client side

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I am trying to write an RMI code for the very first time. The program performs a very simple function of getting the date from the server. I somehow managed to get the server running however at the client side exceptions occur:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: //localhost/RemoteDatum
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:166)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1287360293.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at MyClient.main(MyClient.java:15)
```

My Interface "RemoteDatum" looks like this: (I copied the interface in server to the client Project folder and the stubs were generated by the RMI eclipse plugin)

```
    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.util.Date;


    public interface RemoteDatum extends Remote{
        public Date holeDatum() throws RemoteException; //holeDatum means getDate in german
    }
```

RemoteDatumImpl: Implementation of Interface

```
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
        import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
        import java.util.Date;

        public class RemoteDatumImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteDatum {


         protected RemoteDatumImpl() throws RemoteException {
                super();
            }


        public Date holeDatum() throws RemoteException
            {
                return new Date();
            }
        }
```

The server:

```
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.rmi.Naming;
    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


    public class MyServer extends UnicastRemoteObject {

        protected MyServer() throws RemoteException {
            super();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException
        {
            try
            {
                String name = "RemoteDatum";
                Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
                MyServer service = new MyServer(); 
                r.rebind(name, service);    
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

My Client:

```
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


    public class MyClient {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException 
        {       
                Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
                String name = "//localhost/RemoteDatum";
                RemoteDatum service = (RemoteDatum) r.lookup(name);
                System.out.println(service.holeDatum());

        }

    }
```

I am using Eclipse RMI plugin to start RMI registry and don't know if that is relevant. I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
```

Unless the client is running on the same host as the server, you need to get the server's `Registry,` not your own:

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("serverhost);
```

Then:

```
String name = "//localhost/RemoteDatum";
RemoteDatum service = (RemoteDatum) r.lookup(name);
```

If you're using the `Registry` interface, you should not include the hostname in the lookup string. It should just be `"RemoteDatum"`.

*Alternatively,* if you using the `Naming` class, you *should* include the hostname:

```
RemoteDatum service = (RemoteDatum)Naming.lookup("//serverhost/RemoteDatum");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i tried it out bit it still doesn't work.. I get this error "unknown host"